# Not able to use property 'max.poll.interval.ms' in spark streaming with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am reading around 1M records/batch from Kafka using spark streaming (Direct Stream approach) and doing some analysis with the data which takes around 13-15 minutes to process it.

So, in order to stabilize the system, I thought to change the kafka property 'max.poll.interval.ms' in the kafka params to allow the poll to happen after 15 minutes.

```
var kafkaParams = Map(
     ..
     ..
     "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
     "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
     "max.poll.interval.ms" -> (900000: java.lang.Integer)
)
```

But when I checked the logs, it says:

**WARN ConsumerConfig: The configuration max.poll.interval.ms = 900000 was supplied but isn't a known config.**

Is this anything related to kafka version that I'm unable to use this property. I'm using Kafka version (0.10.1.0).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of the Consumer Properties. You could try spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.poll.ms in the Spark conf.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will try that. 
However, "max.poll.interval.ms" property is a part of the cosumer configs as mentioned in kafka docs http://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

**Tl; dr.**

Simply add an artifact in your pom.xml will do the trick.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Full Answer**

The parameter `max.poll.interval.ms` was added since Kafka 0.10.1 ([KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)).

Since Kafka 0.10.1, heartbeats have been sent by a separated thread, which drastically reduces the unneeded rebalancing. It is highly recommended to use kafka client since 0.10.1.

According to [Sathvik Vutukuri's Spark 3.0.0 Example](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-241-spark-streaming-300-preview-scala) posted at DZone, explicitly add a specific version of kafka client artifact (in the dependency list in i.e. `pom.xml`/`build.sbt`) will 'force' the instance to instantiate the proper version kafka client.

**More**

As the time goes on, kafka evolves. To use a matched/compatible client version of the deployed/source/target kafka cluster is always recommended.

Check the full list of artifacts at:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients